# matplotlib - shape mismatch issue when trying to add more columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, shapes

I'm new to matplotlib and python charts in general, so forgive me in advance if I got terminology wrong.

I'm trying to generate chart, it's a combo of scatter + stacked column bars.

The thing is it's only ok when the number of columns is identical to the number of rows, as I assume either numpy or other libs are generating shapes this way (which is what the error mentions) but I can't figure out how to add more columns, and still remain with the same number of rows.

The result I'm expecting is to add, say additional X columns in my current 5*5 the table + upper chart.

code below, any help will be appreciated, error is reproduced when additional items to data[] and data2 []

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lst_keys_ordered = []
dict_quotes = {}

def main():

    rows = ['bid 5','bid 4','bid 3','bid 2','bid 1','ask 1','ask 2','ask 3','ask 4','ask 5']
    colors = ['red','crimson','indianred','lightcoral','lightsalmon','greenyellow','lawngreen','limegreen','green','darkgreen']
    value_increment = 100
    size_ratio = 50

    """ this config works """
    price = [55,55.5,55.2,55.9,60.3]
    price2 = [55.5,56,55.7,56.5,60.8]
    data = [[100,200,100,200,100],[20,200,50,100,50],[100,100,50,50,300],[400,50,100,50,50],[80,120,40,60,100]]
    data2 = [[100,200,100,200,100],[20,200,50,100,50],[100,100,50,50,300],[400,50,100,50,50],[80,120,40,60,100]]
    columns = ('09:30:01', '09:30:02', '09:30:03', '09:30:04', '09:30:05')

    """ below  generates errors - 6 columns data with 5 elements in data list items """
    """ 
    price = [55,55.5,55.2,55.9,60.3,60.3]
    price2 = [55.5,56,55.7,56.5,60.8,60.3]
    data = [[100,200,100,200,100],[20,200,50,100,50],[100,100,50,50,300],[400,50,100,50,50],[80,120,40,60,100],[80,120,40,60,100]]
    data2 = [[100,200,100,200,100],[20,200,50,100,50],[100,100,50,50,300],[400,50,100,50,50],[80,120,40,60,100],[80,120,40,60,100]]
    columns = ('09:30:01', '09:30:02', '09:30:03', '09:30:04', '09:30:05', '09:30:06')
    """ 
    for i,row in enumerate(data):
        for j,item in enumerate(row):
            data[i][j] = float(data[i][j])/size_ratio
    for i,row in enumerate(data2):
        for j,item in enumerate(row):
            data2[i][j] = float(data2[i][j])/size_ratio

    n_rows = len(data)

    index = np.arange(len(columns)) + 0.3
    bar_width = 0.4

    # Initialize the vertical-offset for the stacked bar chart.
    y_offset = np.zeros(len(columns))
    # Plot bars and create text labels for the table
    cell_text = []

    for row in range(n_rows):
        print n_rows , index, data[row], bar_width, colors[row]
        plt.bar(index, data[row], bar_width, bottom=y_offset, color=colors[row],edgecolor="black")
        y_offset = y_offset + data[row]
        cell_text.append(['{0}'.format(x * size_ratio) for x in y_offset])

    for row in range(n_rows):
        plt.bar(index, data2[row], bar_width, bottom=y_offset, color=colors[row + n_rows],edgecolor="black")
        y_offset = y_offset + data2[row]
        cell_text.append(['{0}'.format(x * size_ratio) for x in y_offset])

    # Reverse colors and text labels to display the last value at the top.
    colors = colors[::-1]
    cell_text.reverse()

    cell_text.insert(0,price)
    print("cell_text: {0}".format(cell_text))
    rows.insert(0,"price $")
    print("rows: {0}".format(rows))
    colors.insert(0,"gray")
    # Add a table at the bottom of the axes
    the_table = plt.table(cellText=cell_text,rowLabels=rows,rowColours=colors,colLabels=columns,loc='bottom')

    # Adjust layout to make room for the table:
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.31)

    plt.ylabel("Level 1 Price {0}$".format(value_increment))
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.title('Integrated Quotes')

    for row in range(n_rows):
        plt.scatter(index[row], price[row] - 1,color="red",s=5)
        plt.annotate(price[row], xy=(index[row], price[row]), xytext=(index[row], price[row] - 1),fontsize=6)
        plt.scatter(index[row], price2[row] + 1,color="green",s=5)
        plt.annotate(price2[row], xy=(index[row], price2[row]), xytext=(index[row], price2[row] + 1),fontsize=6)

    wm = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    wm.window.state('zoomed')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me how to interprete the failing case. If you have 6 columns you need 6 entries in each row in data, but you only have 5. So what's the data to show in the last column?

Comment: Each data item consists of 5 elements, so idealy lets say I would like to be able to dupllicate the last column, resulting in 6 columns total consisting 5 elements each (table shows 2*5 items of an aggregation, still the same)

Comment: If you want to have 6 columns, each data element needs to consist of 6 elements.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for your response and trying to assist, please explain this concept to me as it doesnt make sense. I have about ~2k elements I want to display on this chart, each one is a list of 5 items (shown in green / red in the image). I'm missing something on why should I treat the items as a 2k total.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In your code you are adding an additional row (such that you have 6 rows) for the data. But at the same time you are adding an additional price/time. It seems you only want to do one of those, not both, but I cannot guess which one it might be.

Comment: Time is for labling the X, the price is for the the data table and scatter, the error is recieved when calling bar, where these aren't in use. If you could share code the adds an additional 6th column, over the existing 5 element structure I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Downvoter - can you please explain the downvote so I can improve? I thought this is a clear legit question with samples included

Comment: When someone downvotes a question they would rarely come back to explain. But I can try to explain why this isn't a particularly good question (which may be in line of thoughts of the person downvoting, or it may not be, one will never know). The question does not explain what is to be accomplished, it only shows two codes, one working, one failing. In addition, the code is much too complicated for the actual problem. If creating a [mcve] with only a couple of lines, chances would have been high that you could have identified the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the aim is to add another column to the data, the number of rows should stay unchanged. In the code below I added one further column to the data (consisting of number 50 to 150).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lst_keys_ordered = []
dict_quotes = {}

def main():

    rows = ['bid 5','bid 4','bid 3','bid 2','bid 1','ask 1','ask 2','ask 3','ask 4','ask 5']
    colors = ['red','crimson','indianred','lightcoral','lightsalmon','greenyellow','lawngreen','limegreen','green','darkgreen']
    value_increment = 100
    size_ratio = 50

    """ this config works """
    price = [55,55.5,55.2,55.9,60.3,60.3]
    price2 = [55.5,56,55.7,56.5,60.8,61,9]
    data = [[100,200,100,200,100,50],[20,200,50,100,50,60],[100,100,50,50,300,70],[400,50,100,50,50,80],[80,120,40,60,100,90]]
    data2 = [[100,200,100,200,100,110],[20,200,50,100,50,120],[100,100,50,50,300,130],[400,50,100,50,50,140],[80,120,40,60,100,150]]
    columns = ('09:30:01', '09:30:02', '09:30:03', '09:30:04', '09:30:05', '09:30:06')

    for i,row in enumerate(data):
        for j,item in enumerate(row):
            data[i][j] = float(data[i][j])/size_ratio
    for i,row in enumerate(data2):
        for j,item in enumerate(row):
            data2[i][j] = float(data2[i][j])/size_ratio

    n_rows = len(data)

    index = np.arange(len(columns)) + 0.3
    bar_width = 0.4

    # Initialize the vertical-offset for the stacked bar chart.
    y_offset = np.zeros(len(columns))
    # Plot bars and create text labels for the table
    cell_text = []

    for row in range(n_rows):
        print n_rows , index, data[row], bar_width, colors[row]
        plt.bar(index, data[row], bar_width, bottom=y_offset, color=colors[row],edgecolor="black")
        y_offset = y_offset + data[row]
        cell_text.append(['{0}'.format(x * size_ratio) for x in y_offset])

    for row in range(n_rows):
        plt.bar(index, data2[row], bar_width, bottom=y_offset, color=colors[row + n_rows],edgecolor="black")
        y_offset = y_offset + data2[row]
        cell_text.append(['{0}'.format(x * size_ratio) for x in y_offset])

    # Reverse colors and text labels to display the last value at the top.
    colors = colors[::-1]
    cell_text.reverse()

    cell_text.insert(0,price)
    print("cell_text: {0}".format(cell_text))
    rows.insert(0,"price $")
    print("rows: {0}".format(rows))
    colors.insert(0,"gray")
    # Add a table at the bottom of the axes
    the_table = plt.table(cellText=cell_text,rowLabels=rows,rowColours=colors,colLabels=columns,loc='bottom')

    # Adjust layout to make room for the table:
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.31)

    plt.ylabel("Level 1 Price {0}$".format(value_increment))
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.title('Integrated Quotes')

    for col in range(len(price)):
        plt.scatter(index[col], price[col] - 1,color="red",s=5)
        plt.annotate(price[col], xy=(index[col], price[col]), xytext=(index[col], price[col] - 1),fontsize=6)
        plt.scatter(index[col], price2[col] + 1,color="green",s=5)
        plt.annotate(price2[col], xy=(index[col], price2[col]), xytext=(index[col], price2[col] + 1),fontsize=6)

    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: my error was I was considering (logically) the data to reflect columns while I should have been thinking rows.. the stacked structure had me confused. Thanks again.